# Let's assume that $ XA = AX $. Show that there is such a matrix $M$ that $ p_A(X) = M(A-X), MA=AM$ and $ MX=XM $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $ A, X \in M_{nxn}(K) $. Let $ p_A(t) $ be a characteristic polynomial of matrix A. Let's assume that $ XA = AX $. Show that there is such a matrix $M$ that $ p_A(X) = M(A-X), MA=AM$ and $ MX=XM $.

I believe I need to use Jordan form in order to proceed. I could consider two scenarios: when X and A are invertible and thus similar and when these two are not invertible. Is this the right approach?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $p_A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p_A(A)=0$.

Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
p_A(X)&=p_A(X)-p_A(A)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (X^k-A^k).
\end{align}
$$
Since $XA=AX$, we have for $k\geq 1$, 
$$
X^k-A^k=(X-A)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} X^iA^{k-1-i}.
$$

Hence, by noting that $A^0=X^0=I$ for convenience, 
$$\begin{align}
p_A(X)&=(X-A)\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}X^iA^{k-1-i}
\end{align}
$$

Then take 
$$
M=-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}X^iA^{k-1-i}.
$$